# Calculated Column in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following Grid -

https://jsfiddle.net/ht94wbtr/1/,

please see image below

[image]

in this Grid, i want to have a calculated column 'Total Red Cells' like below sample image

[image]

with the help of Oleg sir, i got this below code which can be used for Footer

```
        var errorInfo = {id: "Errors:", color_name: 0, character_name: 0};
    var i, item;
    for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
        item = mydata[i];

        if ($.inArray(item.color_name, hilightcolorcell) < 0) {
            errorInfo.color_name++;
        }
        if ($.inArray(item.character_name, hilightcahractercell) < 0) {
            errorInfo.character_name++;
        }
    }

        footerrow: true,
        userDataOnFooter: true,
        userData: errorInfo //{ id: "Errors:", color_name: 2, character_name: 2 }
```

i would like to know how to loop through color_name and character_name columns and display the total error count in a calculated column 'Total Red Cells' as shown in the sample image. please help.

Comment: this depends mostly on how are you coloring these rows, are you adding class `.red` `grid.jqGrid('setCell',"1",'name', '', 'red');` to highlight them or adding `grid.jqGrid('setCell',"1","name",'',{color:'red'});` ?

Comment: using 'ui-state-highlight' or 'ui-state-error ui-state-error-text' classes which are the part of the jQuery UI Themes is a better approach concerning if you update the theme for the `jqgrid` in future. it will adjust the colors automatically too

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ht94wbtr/1/ for your reference

Comment: ahh i thought you were trying to count total red cells but you want to have an aggregate of the errors in the 3 specified columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you need then the solution would be very easy. First of all you need define the column where you will be hold/display the "Total red cells" information. Let us the column have the name `redtotal`. Then you should extend `errorInfo` to hold `redtotal` property with the corresponding value. The corresponding code could be like `errorInfo`

```
var errorInfo = {id: "Errors:", redtotal: 0, color_name: 0, character_name: 0};
var i, item;
for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    item = mydata[i];

    if ($.inArray(item.color_name, hilightcolorcell) < 0) {
        errorInfo.color_name++;
        errorInfo.redtotal++;
    }
    if ($.inArray(item.character_name, hilightcahractercell) < 0) {
        errorInfo.character_name++;
        errorInfo.redtotal++;
    }
}
```

You will see the results on https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ht94wbtr/4/

Comment: This is a nice and precise answer +1 for it

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome, reason behind is that I was thinking other direction of using a workaround with `pivotGrid` component used with `jqgrid` which is totally for a different purpose. cheers